# How does a function with 'do' work in this context?

Tags: haskell

So I have found a function on this forum from about 7 years ago and wanted to figure out exactly the way it works as I'm quite new to Haskell and am struggling to understand it.

```
truths :: Int -> [[Bool]]
truths 0 = [[]]
truths n = do
          x <- [True,False]
          map (x :) (truths (n - 1))
```

This function basically generates permutations of boolean values of given size n. So `truths 3` returns `[[True,True,True],[True,True,False],[True,False,True],[True,False,False],[False,True,True],[False,True,False],[False,False,True],[False,False,False]]`

I have seen `do` being used in IO context. But I'm struggling to understand why it works the way it does here.

Comment: basically you are asking how `do` works in List context?

Answer (score 2):

For a list, it works equivalent to list comprehension, so:

```
truths :: Int -> [[Bool]]
truths 0 = [[]]
truths n = [ y | x <- [True,False], y <- map (x :) (truths (n - 1))]
```

It will thus select `True` and `False` for `x`, and then for each item of the `truths (n-1)` prepend the items with that `x` and for each such list return that list as sublist in a list.

You can however here work with [**`replicateM :: Applicative f => Int -> f a -> f [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM), indeed:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

truths :: Int -> [[Bool]]
truths = (`replicateM` [True, False])
```